# Network clearly has latency issues, but ping is low

Tags: networking, ping

For a while now, my internet has been having clear latency issues (high ping and spikes in games, videos stutter, etc.). However, when I contact my ISP, they tell me to ping Google's DNS server, and when I do, the ping is fine even if everything else seems to be horrible at the same time. Pingtest.com has given me results that match the current state of my internet, but using the ping command at the same time shows low ping: http://puu.sh/o1OAa/ecd1826f12.png.

What could the problem be? What can I use to prove to my ISP that the latency is high?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far your description matches a common bug (in many routers) known as "[bufferbloat](http://bufferbloat.org)".

A pretty good test for bufferbloat is the [dslreports.com/speedtest](http://dslreports.com/speedtest)* web app, which measures your latency under load and gives you a bufferbloat letter grade.

*Not to be confused with the more famous SpeedTest.net, which sadly diesn't tell you *anything* about bufferbloat.

I'd be interested in knowing your bufferbloat test results.

If you do have bufferbloat, you should generally try to fix it in the affected router (often requires upgrading to something like OpenWrt and enabling special Smart Queuing features like fq_CoDel and ECN).

In some cases, like when you can't replace your ISP-provided integrated modem/gateway, you may need to buy and install a second router that can run OpenWrt (or some other firmware that can do Smart Queuing) and set that router to throttle network traffic to something like 95% of your WAN link speed. By making the Smart Queuing-capable router a slight artificial bottleneck, you allow its Smart Queuing to restore TCP's ability to do Congestion Control, solving your bufferbloat problem.

Comment: Thanks a bunch, http://www.dslreports.com/speedtest/3505085 here are the results for your curiosity.